# Web-based text annotation

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, annotation

Let's say I post a text document on my website.

Users can create accounts, log-in, and post annotations to sentences in the text.

Each piece of text can have multiple, unlimited annotations.

It's basically like a forum where people are discussing the meanings of random snippets of text, and one can hover over a piece of text to see the entire discussion thread for that piece of text.

Any ideas on some out-of-the-box or semi-out-of-the-box solution to this?

I am aware of [Annotator](http://annotatorjs.org/) as probably the best engine for annotation out there. However, it doesn't seem to have a built-in login system.

Comment: Why can't you couple Annotator with your own website login system? Meaning, it only loads if the user is logged in. . . Very cool library, favorited.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/):

- Open source (MIT License)
- web-based
- multiple annotations (I don't know whether it is unlimited).
- login system to edit

[image]

[image]